# How do I display authors on Wordpress Blog Posts?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a custom theme running Wordpress 4.6.1. I have a separated subdomain for my blog on the site, http://example.com/blog. None of my blog posts are showing the author.

I have tried installing various different plugins, but there seems to be a coding issue with the theme that does not automatically display the author's name on each post. My posts show the date and title, but no author name. What code do I need to utilize to display the author name?

Comment: This question is better fit in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/   about your question, you might want to check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was unaware of the wordpress.stackexchange.com site. Any future questions on wordpress I will post there.

Comment: No problem:) Next time try to post some code related to the question, so it is more easy to find out where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to add

```
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

to your template file.

Reference the WordPress codex for guidance - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was missing from the post php file. Adding this fixed it. Thanks for your help.